# How to detect "blue pills"

Tags: the-matrix

I looked to this question about [what the blue pill does](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39907/what-does-the-blue-pill-in-the-matrix-actually-do). Everybody in linked questions says that the blue pill is just a memory eraser and/or a sedative.

The thing is I remember a line in *Matrix Revolutions* where a "real world" operator scans the Matrix for Neo

> Nothing, **only blue pills**

I saw the movie in French so maybe I misheard the sentence. But if this sentence is true, **how do they know people are "blue pills"**?

I assume Zion doesn't let anyone exit the Matrix with the war approaching so anybody in the Matrix are considered "blue pilled" or ignorant.

Bonus question : If they are able to determine "blue pills", does locating them have a purpose?

Comment: [Bluepill](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Bluepill) is a term meaning _any_ human that is not aware of the true nature of the Matrix, and still has a permanent connection to it, not just those who have opted to "take the blue pill". [Redpills](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Redpill), by contrast, are those that have been ejected, such as Neo and Morpheus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[Bluepill](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Bluepill)" is simply a pejorative term for someone that's still wired into the Matrix and, by implication someone that would be likely choose Morpheus' blue pill (to remain in the Matrix) if it were offered. It would appear that they show up differently in the Matrix from those that have been freed, known as "Redpills".

Note that those that aren't ready to leave will [actually die](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Saviors) if they're shown the reality of the Matrix.

Comment: Thank you! I'm changing the title of the question to be more generic