# Are there three options with the red pill and blue pill?

Tags: the-matrix

There is the red pill and blue pill in the matrix.

Is it logical to conclude there are three options?

Would it be logical that the blue pill does the same as not taking the pill.

Comment: 4 possibilities: Take the red pill.  Take the blue pill.  Take both pills.  Take neither pill. Unless something prevents you from taking both.

Comment: @JRE talking both sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Please enumerate what you think those options are.  From a strictly mathematical point of view there are _4_ options available.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/566/

Comment: @DanielRoseman - re:xkcd - if you tell people (inside the Matrix) that they are in a simulation they die.

Comment: @Valorum Elon Musk has managed not to kill us all (yet) though, and he keeps saying this and even weirder things :P

Answer (score 11):

No, it's a binary choice, Red Pill **OR** Blue Pill (what in binary logic is known as an [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#:%7E:text=Exclusive%20or%20or%20exclusive%20disjunction,%E2%8A%95%2C%20%E2%86%AE%2C%20and%20%E2%89%A2.), or XOR for short).

You won't be allowed to leave, unless you want to fight your way out (and good luck with that).
You either continue on the journey "you stay in Wonderland, and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes" (the Red Pill), or "you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe" (the Blue Pill), forgetting all about Morpheus and this conversation including the choice between two pills, and the fact you have actually taken one.

No third choice of taking neither pill.

No fourth choice of taking both pills.

Comment: So could Neo be stuck there forever theoretically speaking.

Comment: Sure, forever . . . or until Switch and Cypher hold him down and Morpheus stuffs the blue pill down his throat, whichever comes first. Either way, he's taking one of the pills.

Comment: The blue pill doesn't return you to blissful ignorance. It [knocks you out and you end up back at home, basically suicidal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52880/20774).

Comment: From the [Red Pill and Blue Pill Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill) _The terms "red pill" and blue pill" refer to a choice between revealing an unpleasant truth, represented by the red pill, and remaining in blissful ignorance, represented by the blue pill_ So maybe it just didn't work properly on Tiera

Comment: @Valorum Rather than my own interpretation, I've updated the answer used quotes from Morpheus to describe the consequences of each pill.

Comment: Choice three is that Switch whacks you until you're unconscious, chucks you in the boot of the car and dumps you by the roadside in a gutter

Comment: Even more options are available in theory. You could overpower Morpheus and force either or both pills down his throat, for example.